# Check if Gson JsonArray is empty

Tags: json, gson

I am using `HttpURLConnection` to retrieve a JSON string. It looks like this:

```
{
  "status":"ok",
  "testSuites":[
    {
      // possibly one object in here
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to know if the array is empty. There will be at most one object in the array. I tried the following:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray testSuites = obj.getAsJsonArray("testSuites");
```

and then checked if `testSuites` was `null`, but that doesn't work, because it's not `null`. But it is empty!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out. You can use the `size()` method to determine the number of elements in the array.

```
if (testSuites.size() == 0)
```